# can i run a Windows IIS ACI and connect to an Oracle ACI both running in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure-container-instances, vnet, acr

I am getting the following error in Azure when creating a Windows ACI on a virtual network in Azure:

"The requested resource is not available in the location 'westeurope' at this moment. Please retry with a different resource request or in another location. Resource requested: '2' CPU '4' GB memory 'Windows' OS virtual network"

It seems to me that Azure does not support this configuration at the moment, i.e. Windows ACI on Vnet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-region-availability

The reason I am using a vnet is so I can run the (Oracle) database on another ACI and connect the webserver to it over the subnet. Is there another way I can do this?

The images are based on the following base images:
- FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019
- FROM oraclelinux:7-slim as base

I built and tested the images on my local network and they work fine (web server on Windows, Oracle on Linux).

Comment: Isn't helpful to you? Why give no response? The one who needs help is you! So, just do it actively.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Or what's more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACI deployed in the virtual network only supports the Linux container currently. See the message [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#regions-and-resource-availability):

> Container resource limits may differ from limits for non-networked
>   container instances in these regions. Currently only Linux containers
>   are supported for this feature. Windows support is planned.

You can use other services such as [AKS with Windows node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli). Or wait for the feature until it supports the Windows container.